# Ruby on Rails : I want to display the file saved in the database so that it can be downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, download, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to display the file saved in the database so that it can be downloaded.

I do not know how to do it! So please, tell me how you can display the files stored in the database so that they can be downloaded!

Comment: How are the files stored in the database, how does your schema look like? Where and how do you want to show the file (just links, with preview)? What kind of files (mime types)?

Comment: Do you use paperclip gem to store files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to save content of your file in database. Usually, best way to do that - is to create field of binary type.

Then, you can send it from your controller:

```
def my_action
  send_data(
    @file.content,
    disposition: @file.disposition,
    type: @file.extname
  )
end
```

You can look [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data) for more detailed description of `send_data` method

Comment: I would argue that _best way to do_ would be to not store files in a database at all.

Comment: @spickermann I dont think so. It depends on your application and data. Db will give you guaranteed consistency (and all of the acid :). It also gives you constraints, relations, automatic possibilites for replication and data restoring and more. In situations where you *cannot* loose any data, and your files are not too big - this is a best choise.